# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0,

Tags: c#

This is the error that I get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

This is what I have in cs project:

> ```
> <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
>   <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
> </Reference>
> ```

The path seems to be correct.

I tried to find different solutions such as reinstalling the package to earlier version and modifying the app.config to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Nothing has worked.

Comment: Sometimes it helps if you uninstall the dependency and reinstall it via nuget.

Comment: Are you try to restart Visual Studio? Or clean solution\remove bin and obj folders? Is it realy exists  Newtonsoft.Json.dll in that path? You can clean packages and reinstall it.

Can you attach packages.json? What type of projects are you use?

Comment: Normally, you would not need to specifiy the explicit version and just use the latest (and hopefully only) version in your build. Does the file reside in the same place as your exe? And which version does it have? The problem often happens if two imported libraries happen to use different dependencies.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I tried re-installing the packet. I also tried cleaning and restarting vs2019. It is a console application and it isnt a dot.net core app. This is the dll's folder: Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3. This is the path \packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45  and there is another file of the dll in  in the same place as exe file, I dont know if it should be there.

Comment: Have you no another project inside your solution which use an old version of Newtonsoft.Json, sometimes the old version overwrite the DLL of another project.

Comment: I do have a unit test project within the solution. Yeah, that could be the problem. But how do I solve this.

Comment: Ah, I solved it. I update the package in my unit test project and that made the code work without the error being thrown. Just post your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have installed the V **12.0.0.3** by the Nuget package and I got the same error. According to my own experience . some of  **NewtonSoft** versions are getting mad with some version of the Visual studio.

if you just need simple **deserialize** and **serialize** functionality, your problem will be solved if you reinstall the Newtonsoft current package from your solution and install the version **6.0.3**

This version is so compatible with visual studio different versions.

Comment: I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.4" ..  i get the same error when hosting on iis , running on develpment is okay. i dont get it why

Comment: I think you need to remove the pacakge directory from the local path and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I had installed the Newtonsoft via "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution" I was still receiving this error. My fix was simple – I had to also add the "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" as a reference.

```
1.  Right-click "References" > Add > Reference > Browse > C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll > Click the "Add" button > Click "OK"
2.  I did a Build/Clean Solution (that step may not have been necessary)
3.  Build/Build Solution
```

Reran and the exception was gone.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

My issue : Recently updated newtonsoft to 13.0.0.0 and now VS is complaining about missing 9.0.0.0

1. Check the version of your Newtonsoft.JSON in References
   [image]
2. Open Web.Config and change the bindingRedirect to the version in your reference
   [image]

Comment: It seems like 13.0.0.0 is harder to tame. I had to go back to 12.0.3

Answer (score 0):

In your error it is stated that library version "12.0.0.0" was not found. In your config reference the version listed is "12.0.3"

The version mismatch could be the cause here.

When i encounter this issue it is usually after checking out code from source control and for some reason the references are missing. In this case it helped me to uninstall the nugets, check in, reinstall them and build (and check in again). Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: I have installed and unistalled teh packet several times. It didnt work

Comment: try removing the specifically referenced version, just keep the name

Comment: <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

Comment: Clean the solution, close Visual Studio, open again and build the solution. your buiild might have still the old references so clean might work

Answer (score 0):

I had this **exact** same issue, i was working on a Web API and a self written DLL i wanted to debug.

Working on my DLL in the other project gave me this error.

But i followed **these** steps to finally resolve my issue:

1. Reinstall Newtonsoft.Json
2. Restart Visual Studio
3. Clean solution (*i believe this is the real solution*)
4. Build/Rebuild solution

Comment: This is the result of your solution, System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when your project runs it isn't reading the .config that you expect because it is running from a different process. Try renaming your .config to match the calling process.

It might help to give more details about the type of VS project that you have.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like one of those deja-vu issues for me - this particular time this exception was being thrown when my C# EXE file trying to call a web service. After trying to uninstall/reinstall/clean/rebuild/restart VStudio a dozen or so times I finally found a solution which was to just copy the files "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" and "Newtonsoft.Json.xml" to the output directory (alongside the EXE) - after doing this the error FINALLY went away.
*FWIW I realize this is very likely a hacky/ugly solution and not really solving the core issue - I'm just happy I can move on now.*